# How I can override addTarget method of UIButton in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I want the same action of UIButton TouchUpInside control event. For example:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I want to generalize the `buttonAction` through out the application. What is the best approach to do this. Is this possible using Categories? Or subclassing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this method inside class and put the class name into target.

```
YourClass *class = [YouClass alloc]init];
[button addTarget:class action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

or you can get the class using accessor like this

```
[button addTarget:[A getClassA] action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

@implementation A
  +(YouClass *) getClassA{
    //get instance if already initialized or init it
    //and return the instance
  }
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what you want to achieve. If you want a generic action to touch up event throughout the app where the button is used then using categories is fine.
Sub-classing is good when you want to add new behavior to your base class like adding custom layout to buttons.

I hope this helps your approach!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I want generic action on touch up event. Will try categories.